# enhanced ecommerce analytics tracking on new tracker

Tags: google-analytics, enhanced-ecommerce

I wanted to setup a separate account for enhanced ecommerce data so the data doesn't alter the main account

I read [this article](http://www.optimizesmart.com/implementing-enhanced-ecommerce-tracking-universal-analytics/) and followed it closely by setting up a new tracker like so

```
ga("create", "UA-XXXXX-XX", "auto", {
    "name": "newTracker"
});

ga("require", "ec");
```

Then products are added

```
ga("ec:addProduct", {
  "id": "b55da",
  "name": "Flexigen T-Shirt",
  "price": "16.00",
  "brand": "Flexigen",
  "category": "T-Shirts",
  "position": 0
});
```

But here is the issue I have

when I use `ga("newTracker.send", "pageview");`
It doesn't send the enhanced ecommerce data.. 
See: [image: not sending EC data]

But when I don't use the new tracker (but rather the default one `ga("send", "pageview");`) It does work correctly 
See: [image]

What is the issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You created a new namespace, so if you want the stuff to be included in it, you need to put it under the namespace. So you need to namespace the `require` and `ec` command too:

```
  ga("create", "UA-XXXXX-XX", "auto", {    
    "name": "newTracker"
  });

  ga("newTracker.require", "ec");

  ga("newTracker.ec:addProduct", {
    "id": "b55da",
    "name": "Flexigen T-Shirt",
    "price": "16.00",
    "brand": "Flexigen",
    "category": "T-Shirts",
    "position": 0
  });

  ga('newTracker.send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: Thanks! It works!! but BTW you missed the `ga("newTracker.ec:setAction", "<action>");`

Comment: @adardesign Sorry, I only showed update for the actual code blocks you posted, not stuff from screenshots. You are right you need it for that too. You need it for anything you want to set/track under that namespace.